# sed not consistently stripping blocks from log file

Tags: awk, sed, solaris

There is a log file generated by Oracle RMAN that I'd like to pass through with sed and strip out positive validation results.

The original log file can be viewed here:
https://pastebin.com/XhEEs9e9

```
This log file consists of many sections like this:
File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     0              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650          
  Index      0              232975          
  Other      0              716411
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have sed strip out the blocks where all the corrupt blocks and failing blocks are '0'.

To accomplish this, I have crafted out a rather long sed command like so:

```
/tmp/rman.log | /usr/gnu/bin/sed -E '/^File[[:space:]]*Status[[:space:]]*Marked[[:space:]]*Corrupt[[:space:]]*Empty[[:space:]]*Blocks[[:space:]]*Blocks[[:space:]]*Examined[[:space:]]*High SCN$/{N;N;/\n[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*OK[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*$/{N;N;N;N;/\n[[:space:]]*Data[[:space:]]*0[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*$/{N;/\n[[:space:]]*Index[[:space:]]*0[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*$/{N;/\n[[:space:]]*Other[[:space:]]*0[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*$/d}}}}'
```

The command appeared to work, some of the blocks are stripped out from the original log file, however some of the blocks are left behind.

The problem is, I can't tell why... :(

The filtered log can be seen here:
https://pastebin.com/rKgfj28B

Am I missing something with my command? The ones left behind have "0"s for corrupt blocks and failing blocks too, but somehow they just don't match.

Comment: What's a block? Make sure your question stands alone - don't rely on people clicking on links to other sites, create a [mcve] with concise testable sample input and expected output **in your question** to get the best response and so the most help. sed is the best tool for `s/old/new`, btw, It doesn't sound like that's what you're trying to do so you shouldn't be trying to use sed for it. Consider instead awk, perl, ruby, python, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that block of text starting with `File` in your question is a "block" and there are blank lines between each block, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     3              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      0              232975
  Other      0              716411

File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     0              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      0              232975
  Other      0              716411

File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     0              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      1              232975
  Other      0              716411
```

then this is all you need:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '($19 $36 $39 $42)+0' file
File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     3              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      0              232975
  Other      0              716411

File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     0              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      1              232975
  Other      0              716411
```

otherwise if there aren't blank lines between the blocks then this is all you need:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^File/ { if (NR>1) prt() }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { prt() }

function prt(   f) {
    split(rec,f)
    if ( (f[19] f[36] f[39] f[42])+0 ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
}
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     3              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      0              232975
  Other      0              716411
File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     0              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      0              232975
  Other      0              716411
File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     0              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      1              232975
  Other      0              716411
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^File/ { if (NR>1) prt() }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { prt() }

function prt(   f) {
    split(rec,f)
    if ( (f[19] f[36] f[39] f[42])+0 ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     3              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      0              232975
  Other      0              716411
File Status Marked Corrupt Empty Blocks Blocks Examined High SCN
---- ------ -------------- ------------ --------------- ----------
58   OK     0              7964         1280000         8964120502
  File Name: /oracle/PRD/sapdata3/sr3_55/sr3.data55
  Block Type Blocks Failing Blocks Processed
  ---------- -------------- ----------------
  Data       0              322650
  Index      1              232975
  Other      0              716411
```